# Trigger MS flow when folder is created in one-drive

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive, ms-flow

How can i trigger MS Flow when folder is created in One-drive?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until now there is no triggers for folder creation in OneDrive. I tested with file created trigger and fail to fire the flow with a new folder.

Such trigger works in a sharepoint library Then you can use get file metadata action to get the property IsFolder and use an if condition to have a check. If you can use a SharePoint Library instead

Answer (score 1):

Create flow on trigger "When file is created" and then check condition File Content Type = "Folder". This might help you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response but issue is that using above trigger when i will create file in one-drive then flow is running but when i am creating a folder then flow is not running.